How to share and reset an async timer (tokio::time::Sleep) across multiple tasks in Rust
I’m working on an async timer that can be shared between multiple async tasks:
use std::{
    future::{self, Future},
    pin::Pin,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    time::Duration,
};
use tokio::time::{self, Instant, Sleep};

struct Foo(Mutex<Pin<Box<Sleep>>>);

impl Foo {
    fn new(sleep: Sleep) -> Self {
        Self(Mutex::new(Box::pin(sleep)))
    }

    async fn sleep(&self) {
        future::poll_fn(|cx| self.0.lock().unwrap().as_mut().poll(cx)).await
    }

    fn reset(&self, deadline: Instant) {
        self.0.lock().unwrap().as_mut().reset(deadline);
    }
}

async fn task1(foo: Arc<Foo>) {
    println!("starting task 1 ...");
    let start = Instant::now();

    foo.sleep().await;

    let time = start.elapsed().as_millis();
    println!("task 1 complete in {time} millis ");
}

async fn task2(foo: Arc<Foo>) {
    println!("starting task 2 ...");
    let start = Instant::now();

    foo.sleep().await;

    let time = start.elapsed().as_millis();
    println!("task 2 complete in {time} millis ");
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let sleep = time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
    let foo = Arc::new(Foo::new(sleep));

    let task1 = tokio::spawn(task1(foo.clone()));
    let task2 = tokio::spawn(task2(foo));

    tokio::join!(task1, task2);
}


Output:
starting task 2 ...
starting task 1 ...
task 1 complete in 3005 millis
// stuck here

The issue is that only one task completes, while the other gets stuck. Could this be happening because the second polled future’s waker is overwriting the first one?
I came across FutureExt::shared, but it takes ownership of the future. I need the ability to reset the timer while other futures are waiting on it.

After some digging, I found that an instance of Sleep can only hold a single async task waker:
https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/21df16d7595880247642c4fb38f1c365a49de75b/tokio/src/runtime/time/entry.rs#L102
Every call of poll on Sleep overwrites the old waker registered by the previous poll, so the ready state needs to be propagated to all wakers manually:
struct Foo(Mutex<FooInner>);

struct FooInner {
    sleep: Pin<Box<Sleep>>,
    wakers: Vec<Waker>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(sleep: Sleep) -> Self {
        Self(Mutex::new(FooInner {
            sleep: Box::pin(sleep),
            wakers: Vec::new(),
        }))
    }

    async fn sleep(&self) {
        future::poll_fn(|cx| {
            let mut inner = self.0.lock().unwrap();

            match inner.sleep.as_mut().poll(cx) {
                Poll::Ready(()) => {
                    // propagate the ready state to all wakers
                    for waker in inner.wakers.drain(..) {
                        waker.wake();
                    }

                    Poll::Ready(())
                }
                Poll::Pending => {
                    inner.wakers.push(cx.waker().clone());
                    Poll::Pending
                }
            }
        })
        .await
    }

    fn reset(&self, deadline: Instant) {
        let mut inner = self.0.lock().unwrap();

        inner.sleep.as_mut().reset(deadline);

        // deadline might have been reset to an earlier time
        // wake up all wakers to re-evaluate the new deadline
        for waker in inner.wakers.drain(..) {
            waker.wake();
        }
    }
}

As mentioned by @啊鹿Dizzyi, switching to tokio::sync::Mutex solves the problem. This is because the lock guarantees there is only a single task can register its waker since other tasks cannot access the inner Sleep before the Sleep is resolved. In other words, tokio::sync::Mutex helps propagating the ready state.
However, to achieve the FIFO basis, tokio::sync::Mutex is implemented using a semaphore which basically is an std::sync::Mutex<LinkedList<Waker>>. If the completion order of tasks does not required to be FIFO, manually storing wakers in a Vec or Slab can be more performant.

It would make more sense if you use tokio::sync::Mutex instead of std::sync::Mutex since you are sharing data across tokio task instead of OS threads.
And the problem solves itself.

std and tokio mutex

Different Type of Mutexes


use std::{
    pin::Pin,
    sync::Arc,
    time::Duration,
};
use tokio::time::{self, Instant, Sleep};
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

struct Foo(Mutex<Pin<Box<Sleep>>>);

impl Foo {
    fn new(sleep: Sleep) -> Self {
        Self(Mutex::new(Box::pin(sleep)))
    }

    async fn sleep(&self) {
        self.0.lock().await.as_mut().await;
    }

    async fn reset(&self, deadline: Instant) {
        self.0.lock().await.as_mut().reset(deadline);
    }
}

async fn task1(foo: Arc<Foo>) {
    println!("starting task 1 ...");
    let start = Instant::now();

    foo.sleep().await;

    let time = start.elapsed().as_millis();
    println!("task 1 complete in {time} millis ");
}

async fn task2(foo: Arc<Foo>) {
    println!("starting task 2 ...");
    let start = Instant::now();

    foo.sleep().await;

    let time = start.elapsed().as_millis();
    println!("task 2 complete in {time} millis ");
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let sleep = time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
    let foo = Arc::new(Foo::new(sleep));

    let task1 = tokio::spawn(task1(foo.clone()));
    let task2 = tokio::spawn(task2(foo));

    let _ = tokio::join!(task1, task2);
}

starting task 1 ...
starting task 2 ...
task 1 complete in 3009 millis
task 2 complete in 3009 millis

